# Good tires for road riding in winter weather?

Tags: tire, winter, snow, weather, ice

What are some good tires to install for riding the roads in snow, ice, other winter conditions? Besides letting some pressure out for better traction, what tires should I use?

Answer (score 4):

Different tires for different conditions.

For bare/wet roads I've been real happy with my Continental Grand Prix 4-Season with Vectran tires.

With snow, it depends on the clearance through your brakes...
On a typical road bike with standard brakes, you may not have enough room to add tires with traction. If you have a cyclocross bike or bike with V styled or even disc brakes, you can put on something with a bit of traction for snow and packed snow conditions. I like the Challenge Grifo 700x32c Black/Brown Clincher. On my mountain bike, I love to ride in the snow and use Kenda Nevegal tires.

I tend to not ride in icy conditions, but you can create your own 'studded' tires with zip ties. About every 2 inches cinch up a zip tie around your tire and rim.

Comment: Note: The zip tie method will only work if you have disk breaks.  It seems like the zip time method would work well for providing forward/backward force (accelerating/decelerating) but not side to side force (cornering).  The ties would have no edges to prevent them from sliding sideways and they might actually reduce your side to side traction.  I would recommend only putting them on the rear wheel for this reason (rear wheel slideouts are much less scary).

Comment: Good point about the Disc brakes! Very important

Answer (score 2):

Snow and ice are two entirely different conditions.

For snow more or less standard "mountain bike" tires are generally fine.  Lowering tire pressure is NOT usually a good idea.

For any amount of ice you need studded tires.